# BarButtonItems and BarSubItems on Bound RibbonControl

Tags: wpf, devexpress, ribbon-control

I am developing a WPF application using DevExpress controls, such as the Ribbon control. I want to be able to place buttons on the ribbon dynamically. I would like to be able to support both regular buttons and drop-down buttons.

I was thinking something similar to below.

**WPF View:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RibbonCommandTemplate">
        <ContentControl>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem RibbonStyle="All" Content="{Binding Caption}"
                               Command="{Binding (dxr:RibbonControl.Ribbon).DataContext.MenuExecuteCommand,
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                               CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <dxr:RibbonControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" RibbonStyle="Office2010">
            <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
                <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Home">
                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Dynamic Commands" 
                                         ItemLinksSource="{Binding DynamicCommands}"
                                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RibbonCommandTemplate}" />
                </dxr:RibbonPage>
            </dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
        </dxr:RibbonControl>
        <Grid/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**View Model:**

```
public class RibbonCommand
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int CommandCode { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<RibbonCommand> SubItems { get; set; }

    public bool HasSubItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (SubItems != null)
                return (SubItems.Count > 0);
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}

[POCOViewModel]
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<RibbonCommand> DynamicCommands { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DynamicCommands = new ObservableCollection<RibbonCommand>();

        // Regular buttons.
        DynamicCommands.Add(new RibbonCommand() { Caption = "Button 1", CommandCode = 1 });
        DynamicCommands.Add(new RibbonCommand() { Caption = "Button 2", CommandCode = 2 });

        // Drop-down button.
        RibbonCommand dropDownCommand = new RibbonCommand() { Caption = "Drop-Down", CommandCode = 3 };
        dropDownCommand.SubItems = new ObservableCollection<RibbonCommand>();
        dropDownCommand.SubItems.Add(new RibbonCommand() { Caption = "Sub-Item 1", CommandCode = 31 });
        dropDownCommand.SubItems.Add(new RibbonCommand() { Caption = "Sub-Item 2", CommandCode = 32 });
        dropDownCommand.SubItems.Add(new RibbonCommand() { Caption = "Sub-Item 3", CommandCode = 33 });
        DynamicCommands.Add(dropDownCommand);
    }

    public void MenuExecute(RibbonCommand command)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You clicked command with ID: {0} (\"{1}\").",
                        command.CommandCode, command.Caption), "Bound Ribbon Control");
    }
}
```

This code does successfully populate the ribbon with items I added in my DynamicCommands collection, but I would like to support drop-down buttons for items with anything in the SubItems collection (the third button on my example above).

Is there a way to conditionally change the type of control displayed in a DataTemplate. If the object's HasSubItems is true, I would like a BarSubItem placed on the ribbon. If it is false, I will keep the BarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is regular WPF rather than UWP, and if the DataContexts of your subitems are of different types, you can define multiple `DataTemplates` with `DataType` attributes in the RibbonPageGroup's resources (where they won't be in scope for anything that doesn't need them), and get rid of that `ItemTemplate` attribute:

```
<dxr:RibbonPageGroup 
    Caption="Dynamic Commands" 
    ItemLinksSource="{Binding DynamicCommands}">
    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RibbonCommand}">
            <!-- XAML stuff -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SpecialRibbonCommand}">
            <!-- Totally different XAML stuff -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup.Resources>

    <!-- etc -->
```

For another option, you should be able to write a [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) and give it to the [`RibbonControl`'s `ToolbarItemTemplateSelector` property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfRibbonRibbonControl_ToolbarItemTemplateSelectortopic) or the [`RibbonPageGroup`'s `ItemTemplateSelector`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfRibbonRibbonPageGroup_ItemTemplateSelectortopic) property.

Lastly, write one complicated `DataTemplate` with multiple child controls superimposed in a `Grid`, and a series of triggers that show only the appropriate one based on properties of the `DataContext`. If you've only got two different options to handle, this may be the quickest and easiest route.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RibbonCommandTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="OneThing" />
        <Label x:Name="AnotherThing" />
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSubItems}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="OneThing" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="AnotherThing" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <!-- Other triggers for HasSubItems == False, whatever -->
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

This seems pretty crude, but I've done it so much in WPF that I'm getting desensitized to it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this using a DataTemplateSelector class:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using RibbonDynamicButtons.ViewModels;

namespace RibbonDynamicButtons.Selectors
{
    public class RibbonCommandSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate CommandTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate SubCommandTemplate { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if(item is RibbonCommand)
            {
                RibbonCommand command = (RibbonCommand)item;
                if (command.HasSubItems)
                    return SubCommandTemplate; 
                else
                    return CommandTemplate;
            }

            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
    }
}
```

I added my selector to the xaml as follows:

```
<UserControl
    ...
    xmlns:Selectors="clr-namespace:RibbonDynamicButtons.Selectors">
    <UserControlResources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RibbonSubItemTemplate">
            <ContentControl>
                <dxb:BarButtonItem RibbonStyle="SmallWithText" Content="{Binding Caption}"
                    Command="{Binding (dxr:RibbonControl.Ribbon).DataContext.MenuExecuteCommand,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Selectors:RibbonCommandSelector x:Key="RibbonCommandSelector">
            <Selectors:RibbonCommandSelector.CommandTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem RibbonStyle="All"
                            Content="{Binding Caption}"
                            Command="{Binding (dxr:RibbonControl.Ribbon).DataContext.MenuExecuteCommand,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>    
            </Selectors:RibbonCommandSelector.CommandTemplate>

            <Selectors:RibbonCommandSelector.SubCommandTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                        <dxb:BarSubItem RibbonStyle="All" Content="{Binding Caption}"
                            ItemLinksSource="{Binding SubItems}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RibbonSubItemTemplate}" />
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Selectors:RibbonCommandSelector.SubCommandTemplate>
        </Selectors:RibbonCommandSelector>
    </UserControlResources>
```

I bind the ItemTemplateSelector to my selector on the RibbonPageGroup:

```
<dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Dynamic Commands" ItemLinksSource="{Binding DynamicCommands}"
                     ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource RibbonCommandSelector}" />
```

I did not need to make any changes to the View Model I included on my original question.